uwp app hangs when device goes to battery saver mode
when the app is running and battery level goes down below 20%, battery saver turns on and app becomes unresponsive for some time . This also happens when we manualy turn on batery saver mode.
I turned on allow app to run on backgroud to "always" in battery saver settings , but still app becomes unresposive or i guess it goes to suspended state , i dont know whats happening

May I know if the app is in foreground or background when the device turns on the battery saver mode? The run on background option should work for background activity only.

app is in foreground

I found a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78681903/switching-between-system-power-saving-mode-in-uwp-app-makes-the-app-non-respond are you working together about this?
