Switching Between System Power Saving Mode in UWP app ,makes the app non-responded for a while
My UWP app was not responding for sometime, when switching between power Saving mode(windows settings) while App was running. To Reproduce the issue ,

Run the app
Open Windows System Battery Settings -> Enable/Disable Power Saving Mode
Now try to bring our UWP app window to Foreground(front) -> It takes sometime to bring the app to foreground state from background state.

My XAML Code :
<Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas" Background="Aqua"/>

My C# Code :
RelativePanel buttonsPanel = new RelativePanel();
Button previousButton = null;
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
{
 Button currentButton = new Button();
 currentButton.Width = 10;
 currentButton.Height = 10;
 currentButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
 currentButton.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
 buttonsPanel.Children.Add(currentButton);
 if (previousButton != null)
 {
     RelativePanel.SetBelow(currentButton, previousButton);
 }
 previousButton = currentButton;
 }
 MyCanvas.Children.Add(buttonsPanel);

I just add 500 buttons inside relative panel and aligned the each button below the above one using RelativePanel.SetBelow(currentButton, previousButton).
If I remove the  RelativePanel.SetBelow() line, the app respond properly as expected.
But I want to align the children inside RelativePanel relatively.
On the other hand, If I move the above c# code completely to XAML, it works fine in that case also. Example ...
XAML :
<Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas" Background="Aqua">
  <RelativePanel>
    <Border Name="b0"  Width="10" Height="10"  Background="Blue" BorderBrush="Red" />
    <Button Name="b1" Width="10"  Height="10" Background="Blue"  BorderBrush="Red" RelativePanel.Below="b0" />
    <Button Name="b2" Width="10" Height="10" Background="Blue" BorderBrush="Red" RelativePanel.Below="b1" />
    <Button Name="b3" Width="10" Height="10" Background="Blue" BorderBrush="Red" RelativePanel.Below="b2" />
    <Button Name="b4" Width="10" Height="10" Background="Blue" BorderBrush="Red" RelativePanel.Below="b3" />
    <Button Name="b5" Width="10" Height="10" Background="Blue" BorderBrush="Red" RelativePanel.Below="b4" />
    .
    .
    .
    .
    <Button Name="b500" Width="10" Height="10" Background="Blue" BorderBrush="Red" RelativePanel.Below="b499" />
  </RelativePanel>
</Canvas>

Atleast we showld have 500 Buttons inside the relative panel to reproduce the issue.
I don't know why this is happening, when i write the code completely in XAML , it works fine only. But if I add the buttons in C# and aligned relatively, the app won't respond properly while switching between power saving mode.
I think the issue is with setting the Relativepanel.SetBelow() line.
My Sample Project link (PowerSavingSample)...

I can reproduce same behavior, I presume the problem is also with RelativePanel.
Could you please tell me what your scenario is? Why do you want to use RelativePanel?

in our project , we use relativePanel overall the app for responsive UI !!

In my test, I put 500 Buttons into StackPanel with Orientation.Vertical to achieve the same effect, and it did not get stuck when switching Power Saving Mode. Put these buttons into StackPanel and then into RelativePanel, can it meet your needs?

No. It should be in RelativePanel. I created this sample just for understanding purpose. In our Enterprise Project we use RelativePanels overall app !! we can't change at every place !! we need solution and root cause for this issue !

is there any update ?
